# How to make rsync to use relative path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I want to sync remote database copy using command

```
rsync --relative user@remote:/backup/databases/*.sql /backup/snapshots/
```

As it's result command creates file `/backup/snapshots/backup/databases/mysql.sql`. How can I force it to put file in `/backup/snapshots/mysql.sql`? It's mandatory that source must be remote (it's part of more complex script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `--relative` option.